# Crystal Reports Line Chart Color Highlighting Sometimes Doesn't Work

Tags: vb.net, charts, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have a report built in Crystal Reports XI (11.5.12.1838) that I'm calling from my VB.NET (VS 2017) application to display historical information about loss ratio for our clients.  In the report, I have two line charts to display/suppress conditionally based on the amount of data the report contains - one chart is displayed if the report has more than two years worth of data, while another is displayed for two years or less worth of data.  The charts are basically identical in design, it's just the one for three or more years reports on annual percentages, whereas the other reports monthly values.

In these line charts, I have a trend line, a fixed line identifying a "break point" for acceptable values, and then I have set up conditional color highlighting for the data points depending on whether they fall above or below that break point.  One of these charts - the "three or more years" one - works perfectly as expected.
[image: Line Chart where Color Highlight rules are correctly applied]

The other one, however, refuses to apply the Color Highlight rules:
[image: Line Chart where Color Highlight rules are not applied]

As I said above, the two charts are, for all intents and purposes, identical in design, so I'm not sure why one would correctly apply the highlighting rules while the other doesn't.  For reference, here's a screenshot of the *Color Highlight* settings in the **Chart Expert** for both charts:
[image: Chart Expert settings comparison]

In case it matters, these two charts are in separate sections of the same group footer.  The "by Month" chart is in "**Group Footer #1a**", while the "by Year" chart is in "**Group Footer #1b**".  When I originally created the charts, I got one working, then copy/pasted the "known good" chart into the second footer section and adjusted the settings for what data points to display. Oddly, the "copied" version of the line chart seems to be the one that's working correctly.

This problem occurs whether I generate the report from my application, ***OR*** do a preview of the report directly in the Crystal Reports UI (the *"Print Preview"* option from the **View** menu or **`[CTRL]+[R]`**), so I'm fairly confident that the problem is something in the report itself that I'm either overlooking or simply unaware of.

---

**UPDATE:** - Testing in a completely different environment (*Thank you **@jhenrique** for your assistance*) produced the expected results: both charts show the color highlighting normally.  Using the *exact same* data and report file from my machine, however, still won't display the monthly report data with the appropriate highlighting.  I had one of my users test the report from the "live" application, but the color highlighting (on *JUST* the monthly data) doesn't work there either.

**CONCLUSIONS** (so far):

1. The report itself is fine. All of my formulas and settings are correct for accomplishing my intended goals as evidenced by testing in a completely different environment.
2. The data is fine. All my testing used the same sample XML file as the data source so as to eliminate as many variables as possible.
3. The application itself is fine.  The reports will generate without error, even if the specific formatting on this one line chart doesn't get applied as expected.
4. It *appears* to be something to do with versioning/system files. The only difference between my machine and the one on which it apparently worked correctly is that @jhenrique is apparently using Crystal Reports version 12.4.0.966, whereas I'm using version 11.5.12.1838.

However, I'm still not 100% convinced because my internal user's results don't necessarily line up with this last assumption. Using the same report (`.rpt` file), the same data, and a fresh install of the latest available CR runtime still fails to produce a monthly chart with color highlighting, while the yearly chart seems to work perfectly.  If the problem had to do with versioning, I would think that BOTH charts would display incorrectly.

Comment: Could you share the reports so we can reproduce the problem? Do you know if the report with errors is being deployed correctly into your server? Can you copy and paste the report that works and then adjust it so it will be the copy of the other report and then test again, to check if the dots are changing the colors?

Comment: @jhenrique - As stated, this is a single report with two line charts in separate group footers.  When I created the charts, I got one working, then copy/pasted the chart into the second footer section and adjusted the settings for what data points to display.  Oddly, the "copied" version of the line chart seems to be the one that's working correctly.  The report exhibits the same behavior both at design time in the CR UI as well as during application execution from deployment. ***(cont.)***

Comment: Here is a link to a ZIP file containing the report file and some sample data.  You can switch between views by renaming the XML file for the data you want to look at to just **`ReportData.xml`** (*remove everything from the first underscore to just before the extension*).  Obviously, you'll have to adjust the file path in the CR file to whatever path you choose to store the XML files.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MmMTLf3d56hoLDHgoGrLF34_feNMLXOq/view?usp=sharing

Comment: One more doubt, when you say "do a preview of the report directly in the Crystal Reports UI" you mean you are hiting F5, (visualize mode), is that correct? So you hit F5 and the "Loss Ratio by Month" chart doesn't work, is my assumption correct?

Comment: @jhenrique - Sorry, no.  I'm referring to the "*Print Preview*" option (**`[CTRL]+[R]`** or from the **View** menu) in the Crystal Reports application where the report was actually designed and built.

Comment: I know it's not and answer, but I renamed both reports, opened each one with it's corresponding XML, changed the crystal version to 12 and I can preview, print, and everythings seens to be working. Both charts are printings the dots correctly. Try this one https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnozPJLZ7Q24xUrMPk3bklcyvApo and tell me if you can reproduce it. Use different names, choose one XML for each report, then [CTRL]+[R]. Both charts work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193166/discussion-between-jhenrique-and-g-hosa-phat).